# Does ActionBarSherlock allow to enable/disable an ActionBar.Tab?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

In my app I want to use ActionBarSherlock because it completely fit to the project.
The only problem I have is that I have a screen with tabs and some of them need to be disabled:
[image]

Only the third tab should be clickable.
Other category will be enabled in next screens when the user's logged in.

Is there a clean way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you handle that behaviour in the TabListener? and revert the tab back to tab3 if the others haven't been enabled.

```
myTab.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //if not tab3 & not enabled revert to tab 3 
        actionbar.selectTab(tab3)   
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
})
```

Comment: is it possible to disable the tabs, as I would disable a button?